# order by field greater than 0

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

suppose I've these rows in my database :

```
1
0
5
2
0
3
3
5
0
5
```

I want to sort my fields , I need to return fields with not zero value first and when with zero value  , the sorted rows should look like this

```
1
5
2
3
3
5
5
0
0
0
```

I don't whant to sort by number , I want to show 0 values at last ,

I've this code but it sort them by number  :

```
 ORDER BY cASE WHEN num_mojud = 0 THEN num_mojud END ASC,CASE WHEN num_mojud > 0 THEN num_mojud END ASC
or
ORDER BY IF (num_mojud = 0, 9999999, num_mojud )
```

how can I do so ?

Comment: That pattern seems random, other than manually sorting it, I'm not sure it is possible as is, though, I could be wrong.

Comment: You need a column that specifies the ordering for the rows that don't have zeros.

Comment: ORDER BY IF(num_mojud=0,1,0)

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL, you can use two keys for a sort.  Note that SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So, naively, you can put the zeroes first just by sorting by the value (assuming the values are non-negative):

```
order by num_mojud
```

That doesn't seem to do what you want.  You can put the zeros first and the rest in an *arbitrary* order by doing:

```
order by (num_mojud = 0) desc
```

MySQL treats booleans as numbers, with "1" for true and "0" for false.  Hence, the `desc` on the order by key.

You can put the zeros first the rest in a *random* order by doing:

```
order by (num_mojud = 0) desc, rand()
```

You can put the zeros first and retain the order of the rest if you have a column that has the ordering you want:

```
order by (num_mojud = 0) desc, id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select num_mojud
from MyTable
order by case when num_mojud is 0 then 1 else 0 end, num_mojud
```

Comment: Note using 'IS' did not work for me but using '=' did. `order by case when num_mojud = 0 then 1 else 0 end, num_mojud`

Answer (score 0):

you can select `num_mojud` from a custom table.

First one : `SELECT num_mojud FROM tableName WHERE num_mojud > 0` get all number greater than 0
Second one : `SELECT num_mojud FROM tableName WHERE num_mojud = 0` all numbers are equals to 0

```
SELECT num_mojud 
FROM (
    (SELECT num_mojud FROM tableName WHERE num_mojud > 0) 
    UNION
    (SELECT num_mojud FROM tableName WHERE num_mojud = 0)
) as myCustomTable
```